# What would be the proper vite.config.js configuration if i am using vuejs 3 with a base path URL inside a wordpress site and my assets don't show up?

Tags: wordpress, vuejs3, vite, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have managed to create a plugin using vue3 with vite for a wordpress site and it is using vue-router to handle some plugin routes at the wordpress admin panel. Basically, to manage all my plugin options at a specific path.

The problem I have is that I can get to call my index.js and style.css file which are the dist files which contain all my vue-js app , but when I don't know how to properly route each asset if all of them will be generated at my dists directory.

My folder structure is the following:
[image]

My current vite.config.ts is the following:

```js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        inlineDynamicImports: true,
        entryFileNames: 'assets/[name].js',
        assetFileNames: `assets/[name].[ext]`
      }
    },
    //outDir: '../dist'
  }
})
```

At the moment I am not able to show my assets as I am getting a 404 error:

[image]

So I'm getting a 404 error at `https://vue-plugin.test/assets/logo.png`

How should I register my dist/assets directory to be properly accessible through wordpress/vue and read my *.png images?

I've already managed to register the scripts using

`wp_register_script( 'vue-app', RCRC_PLUGIN_URL . 'dist/assets/index.js', array(), wp_rand(), true );`

I've already registered the styles using:

`wp_register_style( 'vue-app', RCRC_PLUGIN_URL . 'dist/assets/index.css', array(), true, 'all' );`